# How to create python packages where individual modules don't need to imported specifically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

Apologies, I feel this is well worn territory, but I've looked hard and I'm still struggling with importing my python modules I have written. More specifically, I can only reference a module if I import directly. For compatibility with other packages, I need to use python-2.7.

For example, for package brcfiles.

File structure of brcfiles:

```
brcfiles/
   LICENSE
   README.md
   setup.py
   brcfiles/
      __init__.py
      files.py
      samples.py
```

Contents of **init**.py:

```
$ cat /path_to_pkg/brcfiles/brcfiles/__init__.py
__all__ = ['files', 'samples']
```

My .bash_profile has the following line (I didn't pip install brcfiles yet--still developing):

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path_to_pkg/brcfiles
```

If I load modules individually, I get the desired behavior, and can access the module contents.

```
>>> import brcfiles.files
>>> brcfiles.files
<module 'brcfiles.files' from '/path_to_pkg/packages/brcfiles/brcfiles/files.pyc'>
```

But if import the entire package, I can't reference individual modules.

```
>>> import brcfiles
>>> brcfiles.files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'files'
```

FWIW, the following works, but I don't like the namespace problems this method creates.

```
>>> from brcfiles import *
>>> files
<module 'brcfiles.files' from '/path_to_pkg/packages/brcfiles/brcfiles/files.pyc'>
```

The solution above could work for now, but I feel this issue is symptomatic of something I'm doing wrong. This will likely be the cornerstone for a lot of my future bioinformatic pipelines, so I'd like to have it done correctly. Obviously, I'm fairly new to creating python packages, so sincere thanks to those who take the time to help!

Comment: Have you tried importing the submodules in `__init__.py`?

Comment: Thanks! I added `from . import files` to `__init__.py` and it works as desired! I thought I was doing the equivalent by setting `__all__`, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the syntax of import command.
`import brcfiles.files` : Import module 'files' from package brcfiles
`import brcfiles` : Import package brcfiles (i.e., code inside ***init***.py of the package)
`from brcfiles import *`: Import all modules (files, samples) from package brcfiles.
You cannot do import brcfiles, and then brcfiles.files. Because the statement imported only brcfiles(_**init**) and not other modules in brcfiles. 
When you do brcfiles.files, it starts to look for a method or attribute 'files' inside the init of brcfiles, and hence gives the mentioned error.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems. As per @duckmayr, I added `from . import files` to `__init__.py` and it works as desired. Thanks for the explanation & your time!